# What flowers will bloom in winter in hot climate?

Tags: flowers, winter-gardening, winter

I'm looking for flowers (annual, perennial, shrubs etc...) that will bloom throughout the winter time in a warm climate.
Larnaka, Cyprus, USDA zone 10/11, temperatures don't drop below 0.
So far I found; cyclamen, pansies and alyssum.
What other flowers can add colour to the garden in winter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a few, but some may not like the damper, cooler weather during January/February and may stop flowering at that time. Look for Oleander, Pelargoniums, Bougainvillaea, Russelia equisetiformis, Hibiscus, Lonicera,  and roses, though these last will do better if you can find somewhere to plant them that doesn't get full sun during high summer when it's very hot,or at least somewhere you are able to rig up some shade for them during that period. All of these are permanent plants where you are, but some will need care during the heat of summer; they may pause during that time and then start growing and flowering anew as autumn arrives, carrying on through most of the winter. Planting the smaller types in containers which can be moved around is useful,so that they can be moved out of very hot sun during high summer.

Comment: I have several Bougainvillaea. Can confirm that they flower relentlessly, even through our 117°F / 47°C summer. Be prepared to rake the flowers and trim the bushes OFTEN.